# Обновляется вся страница,вместо компонента

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть в одном компоненте обработчик клика, который "пушит" в массив статей новую статью, но после "пуша", обновляется вся страница. Как можно реализовать рендер компонента содержащий статьи 'Articles' (без обновления страницы)?

```js
//'Articles' component
class Articles extends React.Component {
    state = {
        
        count: this.props.articles.length,
        articles: this.props
    }
    renderArticles = () =>{
        const {articles} = this.props
        let articlesList = null
        if (articles.length){
            articlesList = articles.map(function(item) {
                return <Article key={item.id} articles={item}/>
              })
        }
        else {
            articlesList = <p>No articles</p>
        }

        return <div id="articles-wrap">{articlesList}</div>
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="articles">
                <h3>Articles</h3>
                {this.renderArticles()}
                {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary add-article">Add article</button> */}
                <AddArticleForm articles={this.props.articles}/>
            </div>        
        )

    }
}


//'AddArticleForm' component
class AddArticleForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        articles: this.props,
        category: '',
        title:'',
        preview:'',
        text:''
   
    }


    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { id, value } = e.currentTarget
        this.setState({ [id]: e.currentTarget.value })
      }
    
    pushArticle = (e) => {
        const { category, title, preview, text } = this.state.articles
        let newArticle = {
            id:66,
            category: category,
            title: title,
            preview: preview,
            text: text
        }
        // this.setState({ articles:  this.state.articles.push(newArticle)})
       articlesArray.push(newArticle)
    }

    render(){
        const { category, title, preview, text } = this.state
        return (
            <form className = "add-article-form">
                <input id ='category' value={category} type="text" className="category-title"  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <input id ='title' value={title} type="text" className="article-title"  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <textarea id ='preview' value={preview} className="preview-text"  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                <textarea id ='text' value={text} className="full-text"  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
               <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.pushArticle}>add article</button>
           </form>
        )
    }
}

//'Article' component
class Article extends React.Component {
    render (){
        const {title,preview} = this.props.articles;
    return(        
        <div className="card article" >
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{preview}</p>
                <button className="btn btn-info read-more">Read more</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда после нажатия на кнопку срабатывет `pushArticle`, надо вызвать `e.preventDefault()`, чтобы у формы не сработал стандартный механизм отправки:

```js
    pushArticle = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault(); // отменяем дальнейшее всплытие события
        const { category, title, preview, text } = this.state.articles
        let newArticle = {
            id:66,
            category: category,
            title: title,
            preview: preview,
            text: text
        }
        // this.setState({ articles:  this.state.articles.push(newArticle)})
       articlesArray.push(newArticle)
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!! А как сделать так что бы pushArticle обновил рендер у Articles?

Comment: Надо передать новую статью в state `Articles` - как это сделать можно найти в гугле, либо задать отдельный вопрос на ruSO